# Update application Version Number from code c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, version, compact-framework

Hi I have two applications running in .Net 
.Net compact Version 3.5, Visual Studio 2008 
Application A - is used to update files for application B. 
It does this in the follow way.
1. Downloads an xml file from the server which will the new version number and a link to a zip file with the new files.
2. application A compares the current version (obtained using the following code ) 

`Assembly callingAssembly;

callingAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();

string version = callingAssembly.getName().version.tostring();`



with the version number specified in the XML file

3. After the new files have been succesfully transferred - 
   I would like to be able to update the version number in Application A to the
   version number in the XML file.

I have looked at 
 System.Reflection.AssemblyVersionAttribute 
but it is not available in .NET compact 
Any help would be appreciated . 
Thanks

Comment: Why don't you keep these versions in a separate data file? You can run your updater logic just loading the datafile and you are not tied to the complex assemblies versioning scheme.

Comment: Thank you Steve, Couldn't see the woods for the trees there. Going to do that now.

Answer (score 0):

I sorted this by adding a property to the app.config file for current Version 
Updating it after all the files are transferred successfully .